# How to export java project with batch file inside

Tags: java, string, batch-file, jar, inputstream

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        InputStream PROGRAM = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("FILES/PROGRAM.bat"); 
        converter(PROGRAM);
        String s = "" + PROGRAM;
        System.out.println(s);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "+s);
    }

    static String converter(InputStream a)throws Exception{
        InputStream in = a;
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
        String read = br.readLine();

        while(read != null) {
            sb.append(read);
            read =br.readLine();
            }

        return sb.toString();
    }



}
```

What I'm trying to do is to export this project into Jar file, and I need to import this Batch file like this:
    InputStream PROGRAM = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("FILES/PROGRAM.bat");
So it can work in any other computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maven build tool and put your bat under Resources. You can then take inputsream as

```
InputStream PROGRAM = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("//PROGRAM.bat");
```

when you will build using maven build tool the bat file will be inside the jar and will be accessible to your Main class .

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create the Folder with the batchfile inside and place it parallel to the jar:

- folder where the jar is inside

  - jar
  - FILES

    - PROGRAM.bat

Answer (score -2):

paste ur program in netbeans then click on  run>clean and run project. jar file will be created automatically